# Strategy for image gallery navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am thinking how to implement image navigation (back/next) feature.
I have 20 or more thumb images on page.
When user click on thumb new view is generated with image full size.
In that view I pass imageID and image path.

1) I was thinking to pass in this view (when user click on some image) array with IDs of other images after that image, but I think this is bad idea.

2) Another option - pass imageID to database query after each next click and get next image.

I can't increment by 1 to display next image because images are in categories and increment by 1 make no sense.

Any advice on what to do here?
I am using ASP MVC.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery Plugins like FancyBox etc.  http://fancybox.net/

Comment: I am creating my own gallery. Can't use plugins :(

Comment: Have you looked at using AjaxControlToolKit ModalPopupExtended and using Ajax, control does not have to leave the page and you get the ability to load images dynamically when needed, same as JQuery. http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you only pass the ID of the image, and resolve all other things in the server side. You should discover the next and prev images on the server, not on the client.

**EDIT**

I think that you already know your path, as you had updated your question, and included option number 2! =) That is it. It is how I'd solve this problem.